# Perl function argument disappears. Why?

Tags: perl, undefined, matching, function-calls

I'm building a stress-system in Perl for correcting students programming assignments. I built a function `check(<boolean>,<congrats-message>,<blame-message>)` that is supposed to help me along the way.

When I invoke it as

```
check(get_option('content-type') eq "text/html","good type", "bad type");
```

everything is fine. But if I dare to do

```
check(get_option('content-type') =~ m:text/html:i, "good type", "bad type");
```

it breaks when the regexp doesn't find a match. Actually it is then equivalent to a `check("good type", "bad type")`. I use only `$_[0]`, `$_[1]` etc. in check() function, and it's not like I had 'undef' as first argument: I can really catch the bug with `die unless $#_ == 2`.

What's happening ? I worked it around with

```
check((get_option('content-type') =~ m:text/html:i && 1), "good type", "bad type");
```

but I'd love to understand the what and why of this odd situation.

--

```
sub check {
  if ($_[0]) {
    $okay++;
    print STDERR "^_^ $_[1] ($okay)\n";
  } else {
    print STDERR ">_< $_[2]\n";
  }
  return $_[0];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`eq` always returns true or false, but `=~` (when in list context) returns "a list consisting of the subexpressions matched by the parentheses in the pattern,".

When you put a list inside another list (e.g. the list of matches inside the list of arguments to the subroutine), they get merged.

If there are 0 matches, you get the 2 other arguments in the list.

If there are 2 matches, you get those 2 matches then the 2 other arguments for a total of 4 arguments.

Your code depends on there being exactly three arguments.

Comment: so I could have used "scalar(...)" instead of "... && 1", right ?

Comment: "When you put a list inside another list, they get merged." -- ah, good reminder. That's why some additional trickery is required to get LoL.

Comment: btw, any chance a "prototype" of `check()` could have forced it to be a 3-scalar-only function ?

Comment: I've never needed to learn to use prototypes, so I've no idea.

Comment: The prototype `sub check($$$) { ...` works for me. It forces `@_` to become `('', 'good type', 'bad type')`.

Comment: @quentin: and it explains why I never realised the difference: an empty list evaluates as "false" when used directly :P